# Can Not send Multiple Values with multiple checkbox in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following form where data are retrieved from the mysql DB.

```
<?php 
    $get_name = mysql_query("SELECT * from premises WHERE status = 0") or die(mysql_error());

    while($motel = mysql_fetch_array($get_name)){
?>
<form method="post" action="includes/loanprocess.php">
    <tr>
        <td width="50"><input type="checkbox" name="m_id" value="<?php echo $motel['ID'];?>" /></td><td><?php echo $motel['name'];?></td><td><?php echo $motel['ID'];?></td><td><?php echo $motel['address'];?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php                       
    }
?>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Proceed to Enter Details" /></td>
        <td></td>
</form>
```

i need to send the values by checkbox to another page. 
to catch the data the code of the loanprocess.php is

```
<?php
    include_once("connection.php");
    $id = $_POST['m_id'];

    foreach ($id as $key => $value) {   
        $m_id =  str_replace("'", "'", $key);
        echo $m_id;         
    }
?>
```

it is not working.

Comment: Maybe try `name="m_id[]"` in your form?

Comment: Can you explain `$m_id =  str_replace("'", "'", $key);`  ?

Comment: name="m_id" cannot work, try name="m_id[]" instead if you want to loop through it.

Comment: name="m_id[]" is not working. it is for separating the array key from values.

Comment: name="m_id[]" shows the array value with key as Array ( [0] => B2465 [1] => B5454 [2] => G002 ) . how to separate the values to insert into DB?

Comment: @RahiM. - it's giving you a plain array, not an associative array. You should just need to swap your loop to `foreach ($_POST['m_id'] as $m_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the name, like people are saying in comments, to "m_id[]". Then, when processing do this:

```
$id = $_POST['m_id'];

foreach ($id as $db_id) {
    ...
}
```

The keys here are meaningless as the array you have is a simple array with indices of 0, 1, 2, etc. For example, if you have:

```
$id = Array ( [0] => B2465 [1] => B5454 [2] => G002 )
```

Then

```
foreach($id as $db_id) {
   echo $db_id;
}
```

Would give you:

```
B2465
B5454
G002
```